# Web2py SQLForm.grid headers misaligned with selectable option

Tags: web2py

I'm using a web2py SQLForm.grid with the selectable option (checkboxes).  The headers are all misaligned to the left with no added column-widths/centering above the data rows.

For example:
Headers should look like this:

```
Header1          Header2
 data1            data2
```

but actually look like this:

```
Header1 Header2
 data1           data2
```

Is there a way to control this in the SQLForm.grid signature, or some other way?

I'd prefer to not rely on client-side javascript to fix this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had CSS style setting in my view that was overriding the web2py formatting. I didn't realize the CSS style setting was there.  When I found it and removed it, the formatting worked properly.  Totally my fault.

This problem is solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).